# Use procedural function in statement Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, sequelize.js, upsert

I tried to use procedural function in my sequelize query.

```
await model.sequelize.upsert({
 id: '123',
 code: 'usa',
 country: model.sequelize.conn.fn('getCountry', 'usa')
});
```

That resulted to these codes:

```
INSERT INTO "places" ("id","code","country") 
VALUES ($1, $2, getCountry('usa')); 
....
bind: [('123', 'usa']
```

I couldn't find any error in the log, but message said `EXEC('1234567') rollback: ...` (snippet of the error)

```
{ 
connection: 
Client {
_ending: false,
_connecting: false,
_connectionError: false,
hasExecuted: true},
finished: 'rollback' } }
```

When I ran the above query in the postgreSql editor, to my surprise it worked and that is the confusion bit. Why did it work on the Editor but not with sequeline?

what possibility cause it to rollback?

I also tried to do this:

```
await model.sequelize.upsert({
 id: '123',
 code: 'usa',
 country: select getCountry('usa')"
});

/// below is what I get from the above sequelize

INSERT INTO "places" ("id","code","country") 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3); 

bind: [('123', 'usa', 'select getCountry('usa'))]
/// this also caused an error
```

Answer (score 0):

A few errors occurred here:
1) Cannot use stored procedure func with "CRUD" query, so the above function is a SQL function - [Quora](https://www.quora.com/When-would-you-use-stored-procedure-or-functions-in-Oracle/answer/Vikrant-Oberoi?ch=99&share=0a1d5df2&srid=1e1y)
2) Maybe there is a way, but from this, I believe `"modal.sequelize.fn(...)"` can only be use in the `"WHERE"` and `"ORDER"` part of the query - [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn)
3) `SELECT getCountry('usa');` is not correct, because the value in the binding section has to be a literal value and not a query.

To why the first query worked in the `PostgreSQL`, I am not sure but likely have to do the way the "Sequelize" is work and binding values and before it send it to the database.